# NSRegularExpression not matching usernames (@) properly

Tags: ios, parsing, nsregularexpression

So I am using the following regex expression to capture all usernames :

```
[@]\\w\\S*
```

If I type in `"@username"` it matches properly. `Result : [@username]`

But if I type in `"@username@username@username"` the result is `[@username@username@username]` . And I want is to be: `[@username , @username , @username]`.

Can anyone give me a hand please?

Comment: `\S*: match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]` (from regex101): How can it detect 3 mentions so? It's one mention for him.

Comment: Maybe it is considering "@username@username@username" to be one word?

Comment: I've edited my question as it was incorrect the first part.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using :  @"[@][a-z0-9_-]+" for usernames and @"[#][a-z0-9_-]+" for hashtags while typing in.

When I have a textfield with already known usernames/hashtags, I use "[@]\w\S*" and "[#]\w\S*"